# pandas: calculate time difference between df columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, difference, timedelta

I have two df columns with string values:

```
df['starttime']                           df['endtime']

0            2015-10-06 18:35:33            0            2015-10-06 18:35:58
1     2015-10-08 17:51:21.999000            1            2015-10-08 17:52:10
2     2015-10-08 20:51:55.999000            2            2015-10-08 20:52:21
3     2015-10-05 15:16:49.999000            3            2015-10-05 15:17:00
4     2015-10-05 15:16:53.999000            4            2015-10-05 15:17:22
5     2015-10-05 15:17:11.999000            5     2015-10-05 15:17:23.999000
```

Id like to calculate the difference between these two columns

here is what I tried but failed:

```
(df['starttime']-df['endtime']).astype('timedelta64[h]'))

unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

I thought astype would convert the str to timedelta?

Comment: You'd want to first convert the date columns via `pd.to_datetime()` and then take the diff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Convert the date *strings* to `pandas.Timestamps`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['starttime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['starttime'])
df['endtime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['endtime'])
```

Then take the difference:

```
df['starttime']-df['endtime']
```

---

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

occurs when you try to subtract two Series containing strings:

```
df['starttime']-df['endtime']
```

without first converting the strings to Timestamps.

Comment: Yep, that's what it was. Thanks!