# datetime difference between dates

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I have a df like so:

```
  firstdate                seconddate
0 2011-01-01 13:00:00    2011-01-01 13:00:00
1 2011-01-02 14:00:00    2011-01-01 11:00:00
2 2011-01-02 16:00:00    2011-01-02 13:00:00
3 2011-01-04 12:00:00    2011-01-03 15:00:00
...
```

Seconddate is always before firstdate. I want to compute the difference between firstdate and seconddate in number of days and make this a column, if firstdate and seconddate are the same day, difference=0, if seconddate is the day before firstdate, difference=1 and so on until a week. How would I do this?

Comment: Whats the question here? how to find the diff between dates or how to delete based on the diff?

Comment: Sorry should of been more clear. Diff between dates is most important, I realise it would be trivial to delete records > 7 now.

Comment: whats the type of the columns?

Comment: All str currently

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33261397/pandas-calculate-time-difference-between-df-columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['first'] = pd.to_datetime(df['first'])
df['second'] = pd.to_datetime(df['second'])

df['diff'] = (df['first'] - df['second']).dt.days
```

This will add a column with the diff. You can delete based on it

```
df.drop(df[df.diff < 0].index)

# or

df = df[df.diff > 0]
```

Comment: Once you are done with deletion, you can drop the `diff` col also.